How to increase root volume of AWS EC2 instance in Python CDK?
In AWS Python CDK 2.96.0, I want to increase the root volume of the instance to run a docker container which requires many gigabytes.
This is my attempt:
ec2_type = "g4dn.xlarge"

host = ec2.Instance(
    self,
    f"{stack_prefix}-instance",
    instance_type=ec2.InstanceType(instance_type_identifier=ec2_type),
    instance_name=f"{stack_prefix}-instance",
    machine_image=linux_ami,
    role=my_role,
    vpc=vpc,
    vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(subnets=[subnet]),
    key_name=key_pair.ref,
    security_group=c9_sg,
    user_data=ec2.UserData.custom(user_data),
)

# Increase the size of the root volume
host.instance.add_property_override(
    "BlockDeviceMappings",
    [
        {
            "DeviceName": "/dev/xvda",
            "Ebs": {"VolumeSize": 150},  # Update the size here (in GB)
        }
    ],
)

However, when I deploy the app, with or without the increase of the root volume, the space remain unchanged:

How can I increase the size of the root volume?

Tried this ?https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2/client/modify_volume.html

no need for the property override, you can directly specify block devices: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/README.html#block-devices

After increasing the volume size either from console or via CDK. You need to update the partition. Follow this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ebs/latest/userguide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html
